# Problems with inheritance and accessing instance variables Python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, tkinter, listbox

i'm pretty new in OOP and GUI. I am using python to make a toplevel using tkinter. This toplevel is made by two classes, one of these inherits attributes and instance functions from the other. But i can't read and get some values stored in **init** method of one class. How should i do that?

I have no ideas to solve this problem.

class Layout(tk.Toplevel):

```
def __init__(self, title, labelName):
    tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
    self.title(title)
```

...other widgets....

```
    self.Scrolly = tk.Scrollbar(self)
    self.Scrollx = tk.Scrollbar(self)
    self.Listbox = tk.Listbox(self)
    self.Listbox.configure(selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE, yscrollcommand=self.Scrolly.set,
                           xscrollcommand=self.Scrollx.set)
    self.Listbox.insert(tk.END, "ciao")
    self.Scrolly.configure(command=self.Listbox.yview())
    self.Scrollx.configure(command=self.Listbox.xview(), orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
    self.Scrolly.grid(row=1 , column=0, rowspan=5)
    self.Scrollx.grid(row=6, column=1)
    self.Listbox.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=5)
```

other widgets with function associated

```
def add(self):... #add elements to Listbox

def Remove(self, opt=None):...
```

class Mod_features(Layout):

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__("Aggiungi/rimuovi esercizi", "Esercizi:")
    self.Populate_list()
def Populate_list(self):
    print(super().Listbox.get(0, tk.END))
```

Error:
in Populate_list
    print(super().Listbox.get(0, tk.END))
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'Listbox'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to call `self.Listbox.get(0, tk.END)`.

`Mod_features` extends `Layout`, so `Listbox` should be a member of `Mod_features` as well.